# What's wrong with this PNG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why can't Photoshop properly open this PNG?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5888/why-cant-photoshop-properly-open-this-png)

If I save this PNG file on my machine locally:

[image: Glyphicons]

And then open this file in Photoshop (CS5 12.0.4 x64 on Windows 7) it doesn't seem to preserve **colours** as expected. It seems that this is an 8-bit indexed colour PNG image, but even though Photoshop should preserve it.

Browsers display it without a problem, so does the Image preview in Windows...

**How do I open this file in Photoshop, so it will look as it should?**

> **Note #1:** To see the invalid file representation in Photshop, just save upper image and open it in Photoshop. Then locate the "movie" icon in the first row, that just renders black...
>
> **Note #2:** icons courtesy of [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/). All licensing and usage should be consulted via their website. Same icons are used in Twitter Bootstrap library.

Comment: Opens just fine for me. What version of Photoshop are you using?

Comment: @Scott: I'm using Photoshop Extended CS5 = 12.0.4 x64

Comment: I am using the same version as you, can open the image above _with_ transparency.

Comment: @CasparKleijne: It opens with transparency on my machine as well, but all colors are simply dark gray (#333)... I'm sorry I invalidly refered to transparency while I should refer to colours... :)

Comment: @Farray: Thanks for the duplicate closing. It actually is the very same problem very well explained in the linked answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open it in Preview and save it anew, this new file seems to work fine. I've attached a "fixed" version here for you:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6296963/fixed-glyphs.png

And for future reference this is the image here:

[image: Converted Glyphicons]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! This obviously worked for you (likely on a Mac). But it should be pointed out that file size is now almost 3 times larger... And that is just because PNG got converted **from 8-bit indexed colour** to **24-bit** one... As it seems.

Comment: Interestingly enough when I open it in Photoshop and re-save it using *Save for Web and Devices* and save it to 24-bit PNG its size becomes smaller by about 31%... From 14,5k to 10k.

Comment: Oh yeah, I never noticed the file size! Well, if PS fixed it, I guess it's no biggie, right?

Thanks for attaching the image to the reply, I didn't have the necessary privileges to do it myself :)