# PNG shows strange artifacts when opened with Photoshop CS4

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, cs4

When I open the file below with Photoshop CS4, I see strange artifacts in the image's borders. More specifically, some pixels turn brown.

https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/master/dist/themes/default/32px.png

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know what the cause of these might be, and what a possible solution might entail?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing you question, so it's more clear. If anything seems out of order, please feel free to edit it back. Could you please also explain briefly what you have tried so far, and what exactly goes wrong? Do you see the same errors when opening the image in another program?

Comment: Very short & quick answer: because Photoshop sucks in interpreting PNG transparency. Try some other software. By the way, exactly those pixels you see popping up here are not *totally* transparent in the original file; maybe they should be.

Comment: >  Jongware. I edit the PNG other software then ok.

Comment: This could be a duplicate of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5888/why-cant-photoshop-properly-open-this-png - at least the image is indexed with an alpha channel, exactly as in the other question.